# How do I pass a parameter in a stored procedure to call a DTS package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, dts

I have created a DTS package which fetches data from a text file into a database table.

I want to pass the file name dynamically from which it fetches data.

Can I pass the filename dynamically?

Comment: Try looking at http://db-pub.com/forum-80500544/dynamic-file-name-and-compression-in-dts.html and the SQLDTS topic on Global Variables at http://www.sqldts.com/234.aspx